# LINQ join taking a lot of time

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am currently using the following linq query

```
lsttask = (from d in administrationEntities.Tasks
  .Include("Status")
  .Include("Priority")
  .Include("Batch")
  .Include("Batch.ShipmentGroup")
  .Include("Batch.ShipmentGroup.Shipment")
  .Include("Batch.ShipmentGroup.Shipment.TOCShipmentManifests.TOCShipmentDetails.TOCShipmentProcesses")
  .Include("Batch.ShipmentGroup.Shipment.Project")
  .Include("TaskType")
     where ((projectId == null ? true : d.Batch.ShipmentGroup.Shipment.Project.ProjectId == projectId) 
         && ( statusId == null ? true : d.StatusId == statusId) 
         && d.IsDeleted == false)
     select d)
  .ToList();
```

but its really consuming time , like up to 30 plus seconds 
Is there an alternate way to trim on the execution time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Entity Framework taking 30 seconds to load records when the generated query only takes 1/2 of a second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686554/why-is-entity-framework-taking-30-seconds-to-load-records-when-the-generated-que)

Comment: You are bringing the data to the machine executing the code using the include. Make the query without include so that it is executed by dbms.

Comment: It's most likely due to all the `Include` calls - you should consider creating a view with all the relevant data and query that instead.