# EntityFramework taking excessive time to return records for a simple SQL query

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, database-performance

I have already combed through this old article:
[Why is Entity Framework taking 30 seconds to load records when the generated query only takes 1/2 of a second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686554/why-is-entity-framework-taking-30-seconds-to-load-records-when-the-generated-que][1])
but no success.

I have tested the query:

- without lazy loading (not using .Include of related entities) and
- without merge tracking (using AsNoTracking)

I do not think I can easily switch to compiled queries in general due to the complexity of queries and using a Code First model, but let me know if you experience otherwise...

**Setup**

- Entity Framework '4.4' (.Net 4.0 with EF 5 install)
- Code First model and DbContext
- Testing directly on the SQL Server 2008 machine hosting the database

**Query**
- It's just returning simple fields from one table:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Active] AS [Active], 
[Extent1].[ChangeUrl] AS [ChangeUrl], 
[Extent1].[MatchValueSetId] AS [MatchValueSetId], 
[Extent1].[ConfigValueSetId] AS [ConfigValueSetId], 
[Extent1].[HashValue] AS [HashValue], 
[Extent1].[Creator] AS [Creator], 
[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
FROM [dbo].[MatchActivations] AS [Extent1]
```

- The MatchActivations table has relationships with other tables, but for this purpose using explicit loading of related entities as needed.

**Results** (from SQL Server Profiler)

- For Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Query: CPU = 78 msec., Duration = 587 msec.
- For EntityFrameworkMUE: CPU = 31 msec., **Duration = 8216 msec.!**

Does anyone know, besides suggesting the use of compiled queries if there is anything else to be aware of when using Entity Framework for such a simple query?

Comment: **[Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)**

Comment: Can you post your original EF query or linq command?

Comment: Is this a first time loading issue or is it slow after the model is generated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423838/entity-framework-very-slow-to-load-for-first-time-after-every-compilation

Comment: How many rows are returned from the query?

Comment: The original EF query is very simply: Records = ConfigUnitOfWork.Db.MatchActivations.AsNoTracking().ToList(); where MatchActivations is a DbSet<MatchActivation>.

Comment: This is not a just a first-time loading issue and all the records (25,000+) are returned from the database on purpose. This is a unit test case we have to see if performance remains within some reasonable limits.

Answer (score 0):

A number of people have run into problems where cached query execution plans due to parameter sniffing cause SQL Server to produce a very inefficient execution plan when running a query through ADO.NET, while running the exact same query directly from SQL Server Management Studio uses a different execution plan because some flags on the query are set differently by default.

Some people have reported success in forcing a refresh of the query execution plans by running one or both of the following commands:

```
 DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
 DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

But a more long-term, targeted solution to this problem would be to use Query Hints like `OPTIMIZE FOR` and `OPTION(Recompile)`, as described in  [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options), to help ensure that good execution plans are chosen more consistently in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the framework is doing something funky if you what you say is true i.e. running the query in management studio takes half a second while entity framework takes 8.2 seconds. My hunch is that it's trying to do something with those 25K+ records set (perhaps bind to something else).

Can you download NP NET profiler and profile your app once? http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35370

This nifty little program is going to record every method call and their execution time and basically give you info from under the hood on where it's spending those 7+ seconds. If that does not help, I also recommend trying out JetBrains .NET profiler. https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Previous answer suggests that the execution plan can be off and that's true in many cases but it's also worth to sometimes look under the hood to determine the cause.

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to Kalagen and others who responded to this - I did come to a conclusion on this, but forgot about this post.

**It turns it is the number of records being returned X processing time (LINQ/EF I presume) to repurpose the raw SQL data back into objects on the client side**. I set up wireshark on the SQL server to monitor the network traffic between it and client machines post-query and discovered:

- There is a constant stream of network traffic between SQL server and
  the rate of packet processing varies greatly between different machines (8x)
- While that is occurring, the SQL server CPU utilization is < 25% and no resource starvation seems to be happening (working set, virtual memory, thread, handle counts, etc.)

so it is basically the constant conversion of the results back into EF objects.

The query in question BTW was part of a 'performance' unit test so we ended up culling it down to a more reasonable typical web-page loading of 100 records in under 1 sec. which passes easily.

If anyone wants to chime in on the details of how Entity Framework processes records post-query, I'm sure that would be useful to know.

It was an interesting discovery that **the processing time depended more heavily on the client machine than on the SQL server machine** (this is an intranet application).